# Emit in socket.io after an express endpoint is hit

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to sockets

I am running an express webserver with a client who is using socket.io.

Basically, whenever somebody hits one of my post requests, I would like to emit a result to my client indicating that the post request was hit. I envision it looking something like this.

**Node Server**

```
const app = express();
app.post('/makeOrder', function(req, res){ 
   // Do some database logic that pushes the order into my database


   // This is where I'm stuck.
   // I want to notify the client that the order is placed.
   // Would it look something like this?
   io.in('kitchenSocket').emit('order-placed', 'An order has been placed!');


   // Last send something to finish the request
   res.send({test:"order placed"})
}
```

**Web Client**

```
<script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    // What I currently have
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5554/kitchenSocket');
    socket.on('order-placed', function (data) {
        alert("an order has been placed:" + data)
    });
</script>
```

How can I get it to emit a message on an express endpoint being hit?

Comment: Have you tested this and if so what is the result if so?

Comment: I tested something that feels logically similar but not this exact code. I will do so right now.

Comment: At the moment, I am not getting anything. There are no errors but I'm also not seeing `alert("an order has been placed")`. However, I've gotten something to print on initial connection, so I know that is at least working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I have to do something very similar, there are a few changes you need to add but this is a general idea.  The main difference is that I am using a Redis server.  Let me know if this is helpful or if you have follow-up questions.

Server-side code

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
      var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
      io.adapter(redis({ host: config.redis, port:config.redisPort }));
      //sets allowed origions
      io.set("origins", "*:*");
      let sockectObj = [data to be sent]
      io.emit('notification', sockectObj);
```

Front-end code

```
this.socket = io(CONFIG.socket, { query: [naming parameter] });

this.socket.on("notification", function (resObj) {
  //Action to be performed
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks! This was enough to help me get it configured. I think the biggest thing was that I changed `io.in("kitchensocket").emit` to just io.emit

Comment: This answer could possibly be simplified to just include the code necessary to solve this problem? So what does this look like without redis? Is it much different? [The set allow origins is a good example in general thought!]

Answer (score 1):

Working Express code for anyone who wants it:

**node server**

```
app.post('/makeOrder', function(req, res){ 
    // Do logic
    var javascriptObject = {};

    io.emit("someName", javascriptObject);
    res.send({test:"Some message"});
}
```

**client**

```
<script src="/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    this.socket = io('/', {transports: ['websocket']});
    socket.on('someName', function (data) {
        // Do client stuff
    });
</script>
```